# way to find "intermediate sibling of parent" directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this directory tree:

`C:\A\B\C\D\E\F\myfile.py`

I want to insert a directory for my packages like this:

```
import sys
local_package_dir = 'C:\A\B\C\PythonPackages'
sys.path.insert(0, local_package_dir)
```

My problem is that many people are using various drive names (D:, E:, etc.)

How can I dynamically traverse up directories and get to `A\B\C` without caring what the root level drive is called?

I'm aware of `__file__`, but which combination of `os` functions will help me go up to the right level?

Comment: Are you looking for [`os.path.splitdrive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitdrive#os.path.splitdrive)?

Comment: The problem exists earlier: **do not do `sys.path.insert(...)`**.  Install your packages normally, with pip, so they go to site-packages dir.

Comment: pip on the remote machine where this code runs fails horribly and I'm in DLL hell, so I have to put the packages in from our source control directories

Comment: So fix the pip installation first, it's not rocket science. You will only dig yourself deeper into a pit this way..

Comment: I spent 16 hours fiddling with pip and package versions/dependencies and gave up. I'm not a sys admin, I just need code that runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at pathlib. Its the new better replacement of `os.path`

You can use paths as objects. .parts would have what you need.

```
import pathlib
p = pathlib.PureWindowsPath('c:/Program Files/PSF')
>>> p.parts
('c:\\', 'Program Files', 'PSF')

p = pathlib.PureWindowsPath('c:/A/B/C/D').parts[1:]
>>> -p.parts
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

Comment: combining this with [`PurePath.parents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#pathlib.PurePath.parents) is probably perfect

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`os.path.pardir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) as a reference to the parent dir (essentially `..`) and then use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to move up your path in a relative manner, and finally [`os.path.normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to normalize your path e.g. from `C:\\A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\\myfile.py` to get to `C:\\A\\B\\C` you can do something like:

```
current_file = "C:\\A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\\myfile.py"  # or __file__ if running from myfile.py
path = os.path.dirname(current_file)  # get the file's directory
c_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(path, os.path.pardir, os.path.pardir, os.path.pardir))
# C:\A\B\C
```

On Python 3.4+ you can also use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to make these mundane path operations more bearable.